# User.IsInRole returns nothing in ASP.NET Core (Repository Pattern implemented)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core (Full .NET Framework) application with the following configuration:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(p => {
        p.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        p.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        p.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        p.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<IDbFactory, DbFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
}
```

The ApplicationUser extends from IdentityUser and ApplicationDbContext extends IdentityDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(builder);

        builder.UseSqlServer("connection string here");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Configure model
        // Identity
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserConfiguration(builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>());
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserProfileConfiguration(builder.Entity<ApplicationUserProfile>());
        new Configuration.Identity.RoleConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityRole>());
        new Configuration.Identity.RoleClaimConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>());
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserRoleConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>());
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>());
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserLoginConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>());
        new Configuration.Identity.ApplicationUserTokenConfiguration(builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>());
    }
}
```

Here is my demo data:

Role table

[image: Role table]

User table

[image: User table]

UserRole table

[image: UserRole table]

In my Login Action i have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

What i want to achieve is to redirect the user to a certain area after login.

The current problem i'm facing is that the function `User.IsInRole("Admin")` returns false and in debug mode, if i look at the usermanager, the current user doesn't have the roles loaded (Count = 0).

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

Ignore the Role Id cause is wrong. In fact the user is mapped with the correct value.

Comment: How could the `User` possibly exist in a Login action?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`User.IsInRole` is checking the cookie. But you are checking this within the same http request as you sign-in. Cookie is simply not there yet - it will be available on the reply or next request.

At that point you need to use `ApplicationUserManager.IsInRoleAsync(TKey userId, string role)` to check against the database.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

If anyone (as me) is struggling with this in .Net Core 2.1, [this link may help](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813).

In short, if you are using `AddDefaultIdentity` like this:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Then Roles won't work as they are not implemented in DefaultIdentity.

What worked for me is replacing it with:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Also, if you signed in before above fix, logout and login again, so identity claims are refreshed. Now it should work.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for days trying everything I've read. Your post solved it for me.

Answer (score 12):

After hours of searching I realized this work with ASP.Net Core when using Azure Active Directory and Roles

```
  User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role,"admin");
```

This Doesn't

```
  User.IsInRole("admin");
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting in .Net Core 2.1 (and also works in 3.1), `AddDefaultIdentity` is the same as calling:

- `AddIdentity`
- `AddDefaultUI`
- `AddDefaultTokenProviders`

To add role functionality, go to `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` you can use `.AddRoles` like so:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()            //<-- This line
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

That's all that is needed. It is crucial to logout and login again as someone mentioned above.

For the record (and just to test), I tried `services.AddIdentity`:

> IServiceCollection does not contain a defintion for 'AddIdentity'...

and `services.AddIdentityCore` (no error until Debug and displaying the page):

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be
>   set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
>   AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

There may be more you can do to get the latter two working, but the code I posted for `AddDefaultIdentity` is all I needed in order to get `User.IsInRole` and other role functionality working in .NET Core 2.1 and up to 3.1 thus far.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had added the user to the role in the database when the user was already logged in. Logging out and back in again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same issue as Kaptain Babbalas and discovered that re-adding the roles manually within OnTokenValidated doubles up the result from User.Claims but causes User.IsInRole to function

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var claim in context.Principal.Claims)
        {
            if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role) claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, claim.Value));
        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        context.Principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.IsInRole()` works on the **next Request** after `SignIn`. In your code, `SignIn` and `User.IsInRole()` are executing in the **same Request**. So to apply a manual redirect, you can put your authentication code in another action and redirect to that action from your `Login()` action as following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ObeyMyOrder");
    }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> ObeyMyOrder()
{
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Now the `User.IsInRole()` will work.