# In ASP.NET Core 2.1 how do I add menu items after the user has logged in based on Role?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have an Razor Web application that has several custom AspNetRoles defined. I want one or more menu items to be shown only after the user has logged in and if they are a member of the Role I specify in the Authorize tag for the PageModel class. I'm thinking that I could use a separate Layout but I can't get that to work. Any other ideas?

The current _Layout.cshtml contains the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand">@Configuration["Agency:AgencyName"] Agency</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-page="/ClientManagement/Index">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I only want the ClientManagement/Index menu item to appear after a user with a specific Role has logged in.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151224/user-isinrole-returns-nothing-in-asp-net-core-repository-pattern-implemented) might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research into how the @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial") code works, I found a way to accomplish what I wanted. In the code below, from the _LoginPartial.cshtml file, I first verify that the User is logged in. Then, I check to see if the User is in a certain Role. If the User is in the specified Role I then emit the markup I want for that Role.

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a asp-page="/ScheduleManagement/Scheduling">Schedule Shifts</a>
        </li>
        @if (User.IsInRole("AgencyAdministrator"))
        {
            <li>
                <a asp-page="/ClientManagement/Index">Client Management</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a asp-page="/ProjectManagement/Index">Project Management</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a asp-page="/ShiftEmployeeManagement/Index">Shift Employee Management</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Types Management<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a asp-page="/TypeManagement/AddressType/Index">Address Type Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a asp-page="/TypeManagement/DomainTypes/Index">Domain Type Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a asp-page="/TypeManagement/EmailType/Index">Email Type Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a asp-page="/TypeManagement/SkillLevelType/Index">Skill Level Type Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a asp-page="/TypeManagement/SkillType/Index">Skill Type Management</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
        <li>
            <a asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
}
else
{
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
}
```

This really shows the power of DI since I only have access to the SignInManager and UserManager because of it.

Anyway, I'm sure that there may be other ways to accomplish what I wanted, displaying interface items based on the User or User Role, but this certainly works.